# Bidirectional Data flow between SFDC and SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud

We know that there is tracking data being send back to SFDC, Ampcript Funtions for Salesforce Object Manipulation or Journey  Update Salesforce Object Activity .
Is there any standard or custom  way  except from above mentioned to send data back to salescloud from marketing cloud.

I am doing a POC on bidirection data flow suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks 
Gaurav

Comment: You are covered with the examples you list in your question.

Comment: I have an example on building a lightning component that gets MC data extension information into the SF UI. I've built a similar process than the one I've outlined that uses the SOAP API, and automation studio to aggregate data, to include a complete dashboard within the other clouds. https://invokecreate.dev/search-send-log

Answer (score 5):

Nope, nothing out of the box apart from the things you mentioned.

Here's a little visual I did some time ago showing all the OOTB data synch features of Marketing Cloud Connect. Anything beyond would be a custom development.

[image]